# I have aberrant tensorflow output (with history) after simple functions?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm doing an installation of python/tf on my Windows 10 machine. I believe I have tensorflow successfully installed but I get output like this for simple functions:

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.test.is_gpu_available()
```

```
True
2020-09-12 10:55:14.092689: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX AVX2
2020-09-12 10:55:14.095469: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:42] Successfully opened dynamic library nvcuda.dll
2020-09-12 10:55:14.120824: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1640] Found device 0 with properties: 
name: GeForce RTX 2080 Ti major: 7 minor: 5 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.65
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0
2020-09-12 10:55:14.122443: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dlopen_checker_stub.cc:25] GPU libraries are statically linked, skip dlopen check.
2020-09-12 10:55:14.127666: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1763] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2020-09-12 10:55:14.603601: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1181] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2020-09-12 10:55:14.603994: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1187]      0 
2020-09-12 10:55:14.604226: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1200] 0:   N 
2020-09-12 10:55:14.604604: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1326] Created TensorFlow device (/device:GPU:0 with 8694 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: GeForce RTX 2080 Ti, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 7.5)
2020-09-12 10:55:52.126774: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1640] Found device 0 with properties: 
name: GeForce RTX 2080 Ti major: 7 minor: 5 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.65
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0
2020-09-12 10:55:52.127397: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dlopen_checker_stub.cc:25] GPU libraries are statically linked, skip dlopen check.
2020-09-12 10:55:52.127971: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1763] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2020-09-12 10:55:52.128321: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1181] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2020-09-12 10:55:52.128693: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1187]      0 
2020-09-12 10:55:52.128927: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1200] 0:   N 
2020-09-12 10:55:52.129234: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1326] Created TensorFlow device (/device:GPU:0 with 8694 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: GeForce RTX 2080 Ti, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 7.5)
```

Comment: These are informative logs and are expected. Your installation seems to be working properly.

Comment: Is there anyway to turn these off?

Comment: Yes, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/40982782/5666087. Set the environment variable `TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL=1`

Comment: You can use tf.test.gpu_device_name() to see gpu.